# What is the correct way to map one custom-domain to many services?

Tags: google-cloud-run

The instructions for [mapping-custom-domains](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#mapping_a_custom_domain_to_a_service) with GKE with Cloud Run works fine for a 1:1 domain:service mapping. But what if I want to have, 1:M domain:services and match with the URI,

```
myapp.com/login  >> login-service
myapp.com/logout >> logout-service
```

## What I've tried

The second domain-mapping creation statement will error as domain must be  unique across services:

```
$ gcloud beta run domain-mappings create --service login-service --domain myapp.com     --cluster mycluster     --cluster-location europe-west2-a
Creating......done.                                                                                                                                         
RECORD TYPE  CONTENTS
A            XX.XXX.XXX.XX

$ gcloud beta run domain-mappings create --service login-service --domain myapp.com     --cluster mycluster     --cluster-location europe-west2-a
ERROR: ... "message": domainmappings.domains.cloudrun.com \"myapp.com\" already exists ...
```

Previously, when using a manually created Knative environment, I could achieve this with an Istio `VirtualService`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: entry-route
  namespace: default
spec:
  - knative-ingress-gateway.knative-serving.svc.cluster.local
  # Set host to the domain name that you own.
  hosts:
  - myapp.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/login"
    rewrite:
      authority: login-service.default.myapp.com
    route:
      - destination:
          host: knative-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        weight: 100
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/logout"
    rewrite:
      authority: logout-service.default.myapp.com
    route:
      - destination:
          host: knative-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        weight: 100
```

But whilst I can apply this on GKE with Cloud Run, everything is routed to the service mapped to the domain.

I've also tried deleting the `gcloud beta run domain-mappings` created, setting the `istio-ingressgateway` LoadBalancer to a reserved static IP, and pointing my domain at the LoadBalancer. However, this just results in `503s`.

Why can't I just point to the `istio-ingressgateway` LoadBalancer and let a `VirtualService` route for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use a `VirtualService` to reroute traffic using the same domain and its path to multiple services.

`istio-ingressgateway` is now the default Knative service hostname (I was using an older Knative version and [`knative-ingressgateway` has since been removed](https://github.com/knative/serving/pull/2434)).

1. Do **not** use `gcloud beta run domain-mappings create ...`. It is not necessary for an M:1 service:domain mapping.
2. Get the `EXTERNAL-IP` used by your `istio-ingressgateway LoadBalancer` (`kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system`) and point your domain at it (e.g. `myapp.com`)
3. Get the Knative service hostname with `kubectl get svc` (listed under `EXTERNAL-IP`  - i.e. `istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local`)
4. Apply a `VirtualService` that maps its route destinations to `istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local`:

```
# e.g. routing.yaml (`kubectl apply -f routing.yaml`)
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: entry-route
  namespace: default
spec:
  - knative-ingress-gateway.knative-serving.svc.cluster.local
  # Set host to the domain name that you own.
  hosts:
  - myapp.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/login"
    rewrite:
      authority: login-service.default.myapp.com
    route:
      - destination:
          host: istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        weight: 100
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/logout"
    rewrite:
      authority: logout-service.default.myapp.com
    route:
      - destination:
          host: istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        weight: 100
```

Comment: Can't you forward a standard Virtual service to redirect it to multiple knative services based on path. And let the knative service has a different pool for tenant services.

Answer (score 3):

The [Firebase Hosting integration with Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run) allows you to rewrite different subpaths to different Cloud Run services. The config would look something like:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {"source": "/api/**", "run": {"serviceId": "api"}},
      {"source": "/charts/*.svg", "run": {"serviceId": "chartgen"}},
      {"source": "**", "run": {"serviceId": "ssr"}}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Good point. Firebase Hosting will allow you to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Things to note if you are using firebase hosting with cloud run: 
Make sure your firebase project is in the free plan
Also, the service and hosting is on the same project

Comment: @michael-bleigh this is a pretty neat workaround, but if possible, I'm trying to enable functionality I know Knative supports (at least when running on Kubernetes without Cloud Run) and avoid adding another cloud product.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of routing is not possible with the domain mapping feature of Cloud Run.

Domain mappings only allow you to map a domain or a subdomain to a service, they do not allow you to map routes.

So for example, you can map `myapp.com` to the service `my-service`, or `login.myapp.com` to the service `login-service`.
But you cannot map `myapp.com/login` to the service `login-service`.

To do so, you need to map `myapp.com` to the service `my-service`, then, this service would look at the request path and call another service `login-service`.

Alternatively, if you are using Cloud RUn on GKE, you can put your Cloud Run services behind a [Google Cloud Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/), which allow you to use [urlMaps](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/url-map).